# How to show if $A$ is simple, then $A\otimes N$ is r.e., but neither recursive, creative, nor simple?

Tags: logic, computability

This question is too complex for me and I don't know where to start. For now, I think maybe I should try to show that, since N is recursive, then A is creative iff $A\otimes N$ is creative so that I can show that $A\otimes N$ must not be creative, however even this proof is quite confusing to me.

Any idea will be deeply appreciated!

By the way, here $A\otimes B$ means {$(a,b)| a\in A$ and $b\in B $}.

Comment: What is "$\otimes$" in this context? Is it Cartesian product (denoted "$\times$")?

Comment: I have edited, here $A\otimes B$ means {$(a,b)| a\in A$ and $b\in B $}.

Comment: That's the Cartesian product; it's denoted "$\times$," not "$\otimes$."

Comment: Re: solving the problem, take it in steps. Can you show that $A\times\mathbb{N}$ is not recursive?